# Trying to reverse string in JavaScript via loop, why doesn't the following code work?

Tags: javascript, string, loops

The code is really simple, but I'm not quite sure why it's not working... THe worst part is it isn't even giving me errors!

```
var str = "Hello";
var lng = str.length - 1

function word() {
    for (var i = lng; i < -1; i--) {
        console.log(str[i]);}
}

word();
```

Comment: It won't execute because the length will never be less than -1...

Comment: First mistake is thinking JavaScript is JAVA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really simple you just have to reverse the symbol in your for loop:

```
var str = "Hello";
var lng = str.length - 1

function word() {
    for (var i = lng; i > -1; i--) {
        console.log(str[i]);
    }
}

word();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the for loop as follows..since loop is running in reverse, it should have greater than -1 sign instead of less than

```
   for (var i = lng; i > -1; i--)
```